# The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I had a question pertainning to Parelle and Task in this thread. [Previous Question Related to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995229/parallel-foreach-not-setting-all-values-in-loop)

What I am attempting to do is iterate over a collection returned from the entity framework via a sproc.

Everything query's perfectly on the first loop but on the second when I try to skip past the previous query results I'm getting an **The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once error.**

I realize the debugger is telling me that I cannot page this collection in this fashion.

How do I use .Skip() and not get that error? I need to be able to iterate over the entire collection until the end is reached.

What's the magic to do this?

Like I mentioned I can loop once, but after that I get that error.

HELP!

```
ObjectResult<Guid?> memIDs = await Task.Run(() => db.proc_GetCollaborator_UserIDs(projectID));
if (memIDs != null)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var t = memIDs.Take(Environment.ProcessorCount)
                      .Select(id => Task.Run(() => projCollabors.Add(new Collaborator(id.Value, projectID))))
                      .Skip(skip)
                      .ToArray();
        if (t.Length == 0) { break; };
        skip += Environment.ProcessorCount;

        await Task.WhenAll(t);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query `memIDs.Take(Environment.ProcessorCount)` always takes the first `Environment.ProcessorCount` items from `memIDs`.

It doesn't "remember" that you took a certain number of items the next time you call `.Take` on it - it will always start from the beginning again.

Because you're calling it in a loop, `memIDs` is being repeatedly enumerated. I'm thinking that's where the error is coming from.

You could fix this by turning it into a list like so:

```
var memIDsList = memIDs.ToList();
```

And then use `memIDsList` instead of `memIDs`.

However, that won't help with your faulty query logic. I assume you're trying to take N items at a time and do something with them?

If so, you could use [MoreLinq's](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) `Batch` extension. (See [Create batches in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq) for more info about `Batch`.)

I don't know if using `Batch` would avoid the need for `.ToList()`, but you should try it without.